# Rails Session on browser/tab close

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, browser, session-cookies

I've got an application where a customer can only have one session at any one time. I've got it sorted so this is the case except in one scenario where when a tab or a browser is closed the session cookie is not destroyed. This then lets them log in elsewhere, and then reopen the browser and lets them have multiple sessions running.

If I properly close the browser down then the cookie is removed, but is is possible to remove them without a full closedown of the browser?

The application is already live on a customers site, so I'm hopefully looking for a way to just destroy the cookie rather than re-writing how the whole session storage currently works, though any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is really old, but someone could find this useful, here there is a gem that lets manage a new level of sessions per tab -> https://github.com/santiagodoldan/micro_sessions, I forked from another repo and added support for rails 4.x